# ReadOnlySequence<byte> parsing

Tags: c#

So i have started experimenting with Span for a message parsing code.
Although the api looks easy to understand i cant seem to find any way to convert the slices to an value.
For example i would want to convert an ReadOnlySequence to int.
Sure i can call ToArray and use BitConverter but that would actually create a new array which is what i am trying to avoid.

Here is example on how i get the slices

```
var DHCP_OP = buffer.Slice(0, 1);          
var DHCP_HTYPE = buffer.Slice(1, 1);
var DHCP_HLEN = buffer.Slice(2, 1);
var DHCP_HOPS = buffer.Slice(3, 1);
var DHCP_XID = buffer.Slice(4, 4);
var DHCP_SECS = buffer.Slice(8, 2);
var DHCP_FLAGS = buffer.Slice(10, 2);
var DHCP_CI_ADDR = buffer.Slice(12, 4);
var DHCP_YI_ADDR = buffer.Slice(16, 4);
var DHCP_SI_ADDR = buffer.Slice(20, 4);
var DHCP_GI_ADDR = buffer.Slice(24, 4);
var DHCP_CH_ADDR = buffer.Slice(28, 16);
var DHCP_SNAME = buffer.Slice(44, 64);
var DHCP_FILE = buffer.Slice(108, 128);
```

and this is how i potentially could convert to int

```
var DHCP_OP = buffer.Slice(0, 1).ToArray();
var integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(DHCP_OP, 0);
```

So what are the options here ? Have i missed something or ToArray is the only option?
Thanks.

Comment: Since .NET Core 2.1 `BitConverter.ToInt32` has an overload with an `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` argument (poking the documentation remarkably often helps solving questions like this...)

Comment: Hmm, my libs target .NET standard , so the only way would be to re target to core ?

Comment: NET Standard 2.1 and newer also include the overload using ReadOnlySpan<byte> (which is no coincidence, since .NET Core's "class libraries" are .NET Standard libraries)

Comment: By the way, just in case you aren't aware of it yet, Span<T> implicitly converts to ReadOnlySpan<T>. (So, no need for you to go through your code changing your usage of Span<T> to ReadOnlySpan<T>. It's fortunately not necessary.)

Comment: So it seems that i can only use those overloads if targeting .net core :(
Now i get the ReadOnlySequence<byte> from the PipeReader and it seem that overload will need ReadOnlySpan<byte>. A bit confused on how to convert without reallocating memory.

Comment: Oops, somehow i managed to forget that you actually start off with a ReadOnlySequence, despite it being written big and bold in the title of your question. Not enough coffee, i suppose. You should be able to get a ReadOnlySpan from the ReadOnlySequence through `ReadOnlySequence<T>.First.Span`...

Answer (score 5):

This was [added](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32588) with `SequenceReader<T>` in .NET Core 3.
It offers methods to attempt reading values from `ReadOnlySequence<T>` instances (which of course only succeed if there is enough data available).

The `SequenceReader<T>` has been documented here:

- [System.Buffers.SequenceReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1) for the ref struct itself
- [System.Buffers.SequenceReaderExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereaderextensions) for actual primitive value parsing
- [Source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Memory/src/System/Buffers)

Usage for reading a simple `Int32` would be:

```cs
// using System.Buffers;

ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = ...;

SequenceReader<byte> reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(buffer);
if (reader.TryReadLittleEndian(out int integer))
{
    // do something with the read value, the reader advanced by sizeof(int)
}
else
{
    // possibly abort parsing as you cannot read further yet
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was probably solved months ago, but just in case somebody else stumbles in here looking for the same thing;

You're probably looking for `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal`. If you define a structure with LayoutType.Sequential or Explicit, you can simply call `MemoryMarshal.Read<DhcpDataStruct>(mySpan)` to get a filled instance.

Edit: I'm not sure why I didn't look, back when this was posted, but I did now and found that `SequenceMarshal` is in Standard 2.1, with a `TryRead<T>` that would plug into my original answer... Oh well, better late than never :)

Comment: `MemoryMarshal.Read` methods only support `ReadOnlySpan`, not `ReadOnlySequence` instances.

Comment: Doh! I somehow missed that part and only focused on the `Span` mention.

Comment: No worries. I didn't even know such thing like Sequences exist besides Spans before I posted my answer :d

Answer (score 0):

This may be a nice helper. Created an extension method. This will get the Byte or an Int - adjust accordingly.

Here is a fiddle with it:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/EUGePJ

```
public static class ReadOnlySequenceExtensions
{
    public static int GetInt32AtPosition(this ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, long position)
    {
        if (position < 0 || position > sequence.Length - sizeof(int))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(position), "Position is out of the bounds of the sequence.");
        }

        var slice = sequence.Slice(position, sizeof(int));

        Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[sizeof(int)];
        slice.CopyTo(buffer);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);
    }

    public static byte GetByteAtPosition(this ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, long position)
    {
        if (position < 0 || position >= sequence.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(position), "Position is out of the bounds of the sequence.");
        }

        // No need to slice if we're just accessing a single byte.
        return sequence.Slice(position, 1).First.Span[0];
    }
}
```